# Delete data from Firestore dynamically

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a project with React & Redux & Firestore, I know how to delete/update/add etc..
But when I have 2 subcollections with dynamic field, I couldn't find any solution to delete it.

If you look at the picture, I have the table ID and user ID, but the fields are 0, 1, 2 and so on.

How can I delete a field from tableGuests?
Maybe the structure is not good and could be better?

guests > user id > userTables > table id > tableGuests which is an array.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I delete a field from tableGuests?

There is no clear way in the docs that explains how to pop an item from an array.
I would do this:

1. Fetch your table data with `const data = firestore().collection('userTables').doc(ID).get();`
2. Use that data to get the current state of the array `const array = data.get('tableGuests');`
3. Update document with a new array without the item you wish to remove (last one in this case) `firestore().collection('userTables').doc(ID).update({ tableGuests: array.slice(0, array.length - 1) });`

Comment: I know this is 1 week ago but thank, it worked :)
Just step 3, I did with filter because it's not always the first one or last.